# Emacs X11 Forwarding does not work but xclock does

Tags: linux, x11, emacs

I'm launching a X server with Xquartz (OSX 10.10.5) using Terminal.app, and I'm trying to connect to a EC2 instance with:

```
##local
$ echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.MO57wSPup1/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

##EC2
$ ssh -X user@servername
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-60008) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) )
```

When I try to launch xclock, I have an X window opening up, but when I try emacs, no window is showing up. For example, if I type "emacs", emacs opens inside the terminal. If I try "emacs &", the job is stopped.

Anyone has an idea why ? I have installed it using :

```
$ sudo yum install emacs


$ which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.3.1
```

Comment: Is it possible that your emacs simply does not have the capability to run as a graphical X11 app?

Comment: maybe... how can I check this ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell reliably, unfortunately. It seems like Debian-based distributions tend to come with two packages, one names emacs-x, and the other emacs-nox, or similar. Perhaps you could check whether your copy of emacs is a link to emacs24-nox, for example (`ls -l $(which emacs)`; note that the target of the link may itself be a link).

Comment: Run `ldd /usr/bin/emacs` and see whether it's linked with `libX11`.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed there is no libX11 linked to my emacs. I will see if I can install emacs with X-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the Emacs you're running was compiled without X support.  As an example, the default Emacs binary in `/usr/bin` on Mac OS X was definitely built without X support.  To check your binary, start Emacs and then in the ***scratch*** buffer type:

```
(featurep 'x)
```

and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.  A response of "t" means you have X support, "nil" means you don't.

Comment: good call ! This command returns nil, meaning I don't have X support. Do you know how I can enable it ? Maybe I should try to install emacs-x as mentionned in the comment above.